# Function: $f(x,y) = (x^2+4y^2-5)(x-1)$. Find where $f(x,y)=0; f(x,y)>0; f(x,y)<0$

Tags: functions

I just begin with the 3- dimension function. I dont really understand how to begin with this problem. 
Function $$f(x,y)= (x^2+4y^2-5)(x-1)$$
Find where $$f(x,y)=0; f(x,y)>0; f(x,y)<0.$$

To find where $$f(x,y)=0$$ i already have the ellipse function $$(x^2)/5 +(y^2)/(5/4)=1$$ and the straight line $$x=1$$ but the other two i dont know how to solve.

Thank you very much.

Comment: if you are on the ellipse, it's clear that those inequalities occur outside the ellipse or inside of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Brian Tung explained there are 4 regions to check. I will explain why this works.

Since $f\colon\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R$ is continuous the images of connected subsets connected. In $\mathbb R$ an open subset is connected if and only if it is an open interval. So as our regions are connected open subsets of $\mathbb R^2$ the images of them under $f$ are open intervals. 
Let $R$ be one of the regions. We know that $\forall (x,y)\in R: f(x,y)\ne0$. So as $f(X)$ is an Interval $f(X)\subset \mathbb R_{>0}$ or $f(X) \subset\mathbb R_{<0}$. In words: all Points $(x,y)$ in a region are either positive or negative.

Just calculate one of the values in each region and you know if the whole region is positive or negative.

Comment: +1.  Thanks for filling in the gaps.  Though I must say, I'm mildly surprised that this particular aspect was the OP's gap.

Answer (score 1):

You've already correctly identified the boundaries of the regions you need to identify:

[image]

These two curves divide the plane into four regions:

- inside the ellipse and to the left of the line
- inside the ellipse and to the right of the line
- outside the ellipse and to the left of the line
- outside the ellipse and to the right of the line

In each region, simply decide whether the first term $x^2+4y^2-5$ is positive or negative, and whether the second term $x-1$ is positive or negative.  Then keep in mind how positive and negative terms multiply, and you should have your answer.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your answer. Can you explain alittle bit more, base on what we have those divided regions and how can they determine the positive or negative value of f(x,y)?

Comment: It's no different from seeing that for a function of one variable—say, $x^2+x-2$—the function equals $0$ at $x = -2$ and $x = 1$, and realizing that it must be positive or negative in the regions bounded by those points.  (In fact, it is positive for $x < -2$, negative for $-2 < x < 1$, and positive again for $x > 1$.)  Here, you have already correctly identified the boundaries of the regions in question; I have plotted them in my answer.  Within those regions, are those two terms positive or negative?

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:**

**2.**$f(x,y)\gt 0 =(x^2+4y^2-5)(x-1)\gt 0$is only possible when (x-1) and(x^2+4y^2-5) both are positive or both are negative.
so,this yields,
$$(x-1)\gt 0~~~~and~~~~(x^2+4y^2-5)\gt 0$$
$$0r,$$
$$(x-1)\lt 0~~~~and~~~~(x^2+4y^2-5)\lt 0$$

solve these 4 inequality conditions and you will get your second answer.

Now,

**3.**$f(x,y)\lt 0 =(x^2+4y^2-5)(x-1)\lt 0$is only possible when between (x-1) and(x^2+4y^2-5) one is positive and the other one is negative.

So,this yields,

$$(x-1)\gt 0~~~~and~~~~(x^2+4y^2-5)\lt 0$$
$$0r,$$
$$(x-1)\lt 0~~~~and~~~~(x^2+4y^2-5)\gt 0$$
solve these 4 inequality conditions and you will get your third answer.